# converting a string array into a struct

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a string array with the contents of the row in the following manner.

```
X ='Xmole(1)=0.0Xmole(2)=1.0rho(1)=2343rho(2)=2343'
```

Now I need a `struct data.Massdensity` which should look like this

```
       <data.Massdensity = Xmole(1)=0.0
                           Xmole(2)=1.0
                           rho(1)=2343
                           rho(2)=2343>
```

I did use `cell2struct` which will gave me a struct like this

```
data.Massdensity ='Xmole(1)=0.0Xmole(2)=1.0rho(1)=2343rho(2)=2343'
```

Is there any way possible I can get the struct like the one above.

I am reading a textfile whose contents look like this

```
    MassDensity{

 Xmole(1) = 0.0
 Xmole(2) = 1.0
 rho(1) = 2343  # [kg/m^3]
 rho(2) = 2343  # [kg/m^3]
     }
```

I am using fileread to read this into a single string.

So any better way of doing this

Comment: are you sure your cell array looks like that? It's a single string, not a cell array, so you'd rather need to find out how to split the string. So have a look again...

Comment: How did you make your cell array? Can you edit the question to show the code you used to make X, as it seems very strange at the moment.

Comment: my cell array contains a single string which looks like that it is a 1x1 cell array.

Comment: i had to use textscan to read the contents of a textfile into a cell.

Comment: If it helps you, you can consider x as a string. beacuse i can use fileread to read it as a string. So any help in splitting it and making it as a structure which looks like the one above.

Comment: What does the original context of the text file look like? There are almost certainly better ways to read this in which will make later operations easier.

Comment: ok it looks like this.   
 
 
 MassDensity{
 Xmole(1) = 0.0
 Xmole(2) = 1.0
 rho(1) = 2343 # [kg/m^3]
 rho(2) = 2343 # [kg/m^3]
}

Comment: Do you want your output struct to have actual numbers in, i.e. `MassDensity.Xmole(1)` to return `0`, and so on?

Comment: no I want my output struct named MassDensity to have Xmole(1) = 1.0 etc.,

Comment: Still not clear to me.  i.e. you want strings? data.MassDensity(1) = `Xmole(1) = 1.0` and so on?  Depending on what you want to do, it might be much easier to keep a cell array.

Comment: yes I want the strings Xmole(1) = 1.0 etc in a structure MassDensity. can you see the txt file above I nead to read the contents inside a string and create a structure Massdensity which has the contents Xmole(1). I think u have got the Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the intial way you presented your data is that there are no obvious delimiters.  Whereas within the original file you have the option (one presumes) of using the line ends as delimiters.

1) Read in as separate strings (may require splitting or reassembly in MATLAB), the individual lines into a cell array.  With `textscan` you can set a range of delimiters and other settings so make full use of the options.

For example:

```
a = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter',...
{'\n','{','}','#'},'CommentStyle','#','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
a = a{1}
```

Ideally you want to end up with:

```
a{1} = 'Massdensity'
a{2} = 'Xmole(1)=0.0'
...
a{4} = 'rho(2) = 2343'
```

You may need to do some trimming of whitespace.

2) Create your struct, using dynamic field naming:

```
data.(a{1})=a(2:end);

data.MassDensity{1}

ans =

Xmole(1) = 0.0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer exactly what I wanted. can you help me how I can trim all of the whitespaces efficiently.